# Run a script on remote host and see output

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, paramiko

On the server I just run it this way:

```
root@web:~# /var/www/PHP/controller.py | cut -f 4 -d ','
    nan
    nan
    nan
```

Paramiko script from external machine:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
    for i in range (0,10000):
            ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            ssh.connect('192.168.122.100',username='user',password='lol')
            stdin,stdout,stedrr = ssh.exec_command("/var/www/PHP/controller.py | cut -f 4 -d ','")
            print stdout.read()
```

but the output is empty. Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: Why have you put "python" tag to the question? Seems it's about some "Paramiko" tool, and has nothing to do with Python.

Comment: @TheGodfather: Because the paramiko tool is in Python.  Maybe he is using it wrong.  Those who know Python may be able to tell him.

Comment: 1) Try to make your program simpler and simpler. I'd start by isolating `paramiko` from `controller.py`. Try `stdin,stdout,stedrr = ssh.exec_command("echo a,b,c,d,e,f,g | cut -f 4 -d ','")`. Does that still print empty output? 2) Try `print steddrr.read()`. Is there a clue there?

Comment: Thanks @Robᵩ. Yeah it prints out 'd'. But I am not sure why it doesn't run the script and prints out the output.

Comment: Does `/var/www/PHP/controller.py` have execution permission for user `user`? If not try with `python /var/www/PHP/controller.py ...`

Comment: With the stderr I see this error: `['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "/var/www/PHP/controller.py", line 229, in <module>\n', '    main()\n', '  File "/var/www/PHP/controller.py", line 192, in main\n', "    os.rename('/tmp/serviceLevel.tmp', '/tmp/serviceLevel')\n", 'OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted\n']`

Answer (score 0):

Same suggestion as in the comments, whenever you're stuck and stdout gives no information, take a look at stderr

It might be that the machine user does not have enough permissions to access it, or any other problem...

Try running just the controller.py script with paramiko and see what happens in stdout, stderr. When you manage that then proceed to cut

+1 for password choice by the way

Comment: Check that the external machine user has permissions for /tmp/serviceLevel.tmp, if it doesn't give it permissions and run it again